# Derefering a pointer to a handle is giving me "illegal, right operand.."?

Tags: c++, c

I don't understand what the compiler is trying to enforce. I have a function that sets up an OpenGL context, and returns the `HGLRC` via a pointer:

```
BOOL SetupWin32Context(HDC hDC, HGLRC *phRC) {
    /* do bunch of work*/
    HGLRC hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);
    *phRC = hRC;
    return TRUE;}
```

On `*phRC = hRC;` I get:

```
    error C2297: '*' : illegal, right operand has type 'HGLRC *'
```

And that's not making any sense to me.

#### Full code copied from pastebin

```
#include "Bindings.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl\GL.h>

BOOL SetupWin32Context(HDC hDC, HGLRC *phRC)
{
        HGLRC hRC = NULL;
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd =
    {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
        1,
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,
        32, /* Colordepth of the framebuffer. */
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, /* Bits of the depthbuffer. */
        0, /* Bits of the stencilbuffer. */
        0, /* Number of Aux buffers. */
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
        0,
        0, 0, 0
    };

        int format = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd);
        if(format == 0) return FALSE;
        if(!SetPixelFormat(hDC,format, &pfd)) return FALSE;
        hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);
        if(hRC == 0)
                hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);
        if(hRC == 0)
                return FALSE;
        wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC)
        *phRC = hRC;
        return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Just based on that code snippet it looks ok. Error message doesn't make sense. Need more info. No other compiler errors or warnings?

Comment: is this the real code? the error message says `hRc` is `HGLRC *`

Comment: @CharlieBurns No other errors, though IntelliSense complains about that statement aswell ("expression must have arithmetic or unscoped enum type"). I'm compiling it as C code if that helps.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Does it? I'm reading this as "the right operand to the unary operator * has type HGLRC*", and that's definitely true for the above code snippet.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes.. [here's the full source](http://pastebin.com/L38ep6Th). The filename is `Bindings.c`; it is compiled as C code.

Comment: hmm.. check the definition of `HGLRC` in the headers.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I see it defined in `windef.h` as `DECLARE_HANDLE(HGLRC); //OpenGL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the real code, you need a semicolon after

```
wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC)
```

like this:

```
wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);
```

Comment: Yup that was it. Don't you just love C/C++?

Comment: @Mr.Smith You only have yourself to blame ;). The language and the compiler are not being stupid here, they see `wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC) *phRC = hRC;` (the line break doesn't matter), and that turns it into an attempted multiplication.

Comment: well, you can partly blame the compiler, I bet clang would give a nicer error message.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath. Nope. Here's the clang output: `xx.c:8:5: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'int *')
    *phRC = hRC;
    ^~~~~ `( All the types changed to int).
1 error generated.